# Add a listener on shell maximise button swt

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, listener

I want to add a listener on my shells 'maximize' button such that an event is triggered when the user clicks on it. In this case, I want to re-size my table columns whenever the user chooses to maximize the shell. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `SWT.Resize` listener to be told about all shell size changes:

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
  {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(final Event event)
    {

    }
  });
```

Note: If you are using the JFace `TableViewer` then `TableColumnLayout` will do the column resize automatically.